# SQL Server - Execute Dynamic SQL for Each Row in Recordset

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions, dynamic-sql

I have a population of students who are registered to take courses for the Fall semester, with each course having it's own particular prerequisite requirements.

```
LastName    FirstName   Course  Prerequisite(s)
Smith       John        ET212   (NS292  And  NS262  And  NS271) OR (( NS272 OR  CR313 ) AND CS134)
Smith       John        ET452   HC111
Apon        Jim         EG442   EG243
Apon        Jim         EG497   EG382 And  EG431
Jones       Greg        MS160   MS150
Jones       Greg        NV222   NV101 Or  NV212
Serandon    Susan       EG261   EG101
```

I created a function that finds the the prerequisites for a course and builds a predicate string in proper SQL (or at least close to it - I haven't been able to test), with consideration for the AND / OR combinations of different prerequisite courses:

```
NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TRANSCRIPT WHERE ID = 'P000021210' AND COURSE = 'ET211')  And  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TRANSCRIPT WHERE ID = 'P000021210' AND COURSE = 'ES251')
```

I was hoping to use this function to build a SQL statement for each row in my recordset (every class that every student is registered to take), execute that statement, and then return a bit; yes, they meet the prerequisite requirements to take the course, or no, they don't.  BUT, apparently **you can't use sp_executesql or EXECUTE() within a function**.

So the root of my question is, since it does not appear possible to execute a dynamic SQL statement unique to each row in a recordset, how else could I accomplish this?

Comment: You're on the right track with the dynamic SQL and sp_executesql. You can't use any DML within a function, but you can within a stored procedure...

Comment: So the only solution I can see right now is to build a stored procedure that loops through every record and executes the dynamic SQL that the function builds.  Maybe updating a temporary table with the result of the prerequisite test.  I was hoping to avoid looping.

Comment: Well, you're right to be hesitant to implement looping but given the information in your question alone, it's the only way to do it. I'm sure if you re-engineered your relational structure you could probably do it set based.

Comment: Ok.  I'll give that a shot then.  Thank you!

Comment: About that re-engineering your relational structure, start with a many to many relationship between courses and prerequisites.

Comment: I have thought about a creating a bridge table that contains all prerequisites for all courses... but when I start thinking of how I would incorporate the, sometimes complex, AND / OR combinations, my head explodes.  I could create Transcript1 <- CoursePrerequisiteBridge -> Transcript2, but it seems like the join conditions to Transcript2 would still require some dynamic SQL on the fly...